# Sort / Order by multiple column values in oracle, in a case specific way

Tags: oracle

Problem Statement :

```
Column1 | Column2 | Column3 | Column4 | Column5
------------------------------------------------------------------------
1      |22           |Y     |Null     |Null
2      |21           |Null  |Y        |Null
31     |12           |N     |Y        |Null
12     |24           |Null  |Null     |Y
12     |52           |Y     |Null     |N
14     |26           |N     |N        |Y
51     |72           |Y     |Null     |Null
65     |32           |N     |N        |Null
67     |76           |N     |Null     |Null
23     |23           |N     |N        |Null
43     |22           |N     |Null     |Null
```

Column2 is just a data field. No dependency on that. But I need to order the entire data set by Column3, Column4 , Column5 & Column1 respectively.
Like, Order By (Column3, Column4 ,Column5,Column1) DESC or ASC . All ‘Y’ in Column3 should come first , then ‘Y’ of column4 , then ‘Y’ of column5, rest of the records can be Ordered by Column1 value.

Expected Result :

```
Column1 | Column2 | Column3 | Column4 | Column5
------------------------------------------------------------------------
1      |22           |Y     |Null     |Null
12     |52           |Y     |Null     |N
51     |72           |Y     |Null     |Null
2      |21           |Null  |Y        |Null
31     |12           |N     |Y        |Null
12     |24           |Null  |Null     |Y
14     |26           |N     |N        |Y
23     |23           |N     |N        |Null
43     |22           |N     |Null     |Null
65     |32           |N     |N        |Null
67     |76           |N     |Null     |Null
```

Do Not want to use any union type of thing. Any Idea , how to do this in oracle ?

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the forum.  You should provide your attempt for us to see as well, and explain what goes wrong with it.  This site is not for us to write your program or query, but if your attempt does not work for some reason, usually we are able to help with that.

Comment: Hi @Hannu, I achieved the desired result with a tedious approach( by union). Wasn't sure how to do this in an efficient way. Even I tried similar type of approach what Tony mentioned but got a different issue that time. As I wasn't sure about the approaches, I was looking for other ideas. Next time I'll post the attempts as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
order by case when Column3 = 'Y' then 1 else 2 end,
         case when Column4 = 'Y' then 1 else 2 end,
         case when Column5 = 'Y' then 1 else 2 end,
         Column1
```

Comment: Hi @Tony , It works... Could you please give me a hint , what actually happens inside, when we use **"when Column3 = 'Y' then 1 else 2 end"** and how it is different from **"then 1 else 0 end"**.

Comment: `when 'Y' then 1 else 2` orders 'Y' first (1), anything else after (2). `when 'Y' then 1 else 0` orders anything else first (0), 'Y' after (1).  Because 1 < 2  but 1 > 0